# Anonymous mmap with near-unlimited growth

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I'd like to declare an array that can start small and grow to a terabyte or so without bumping into anything else or wasting physical memory. There are several of these "miniheaps" with different sized structs in them and I want them to spread themselves out through virtual memory. I can do this if I back each miniheap with a file and that's my main intention, but for testing purposes I'd like a forgetful variant. It certainly isn't allowed to zero the whole terabyte.

The code below works when fd is a file but says "Can't make file mapping" when fd==-1. What should I write instead?

(I'm using linux and have no interest in porting it to anything else.)

```
   void * reserve; 
   // 'lim*PAGE' is 1TB ...                                                                                             
   reserve = mmap(0, lim*PAGE, PROT_NONE, MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
   if (reserve == (void*)-1) { fprintf(stderr, "Can't make reserve mapping\n"); quit(1);  }
                                  
   void * filemap; 
   // 'fd' is an open file or -1 ...                                                                                             
   if (fd!=-1) {                                                                                                                                                                                          
     filemap = mmap(reserve, fileSize(fd), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE|MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);          
   } else {              
     // stp is 1 or 2 and PAGE is 4k ...                                                                                                                                                                                 
     filemap = mmap(reserve, PAGE*stp, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);                    
   }                                                                                                             
                         
   if (filemap == (void*)-1) { fprintf(stderr, "Can't make file mapping\n"); quit(1);  } 

   // fileSize and quit are my own utilities for the obvious purposes.
```

Comment: don't be afraid of using `mmap()` to allocate and zero 1TB. Actually `mmap()` only reserved address space. 64-bit memory address space is huge, it's not a problem to find 1TB of contiguous chunk. Moreover, memory is allocated and zeroed by OS only when the page is accessed. Actually, read operations  does not even clear the page, OS just binds this address to a generic zeroed page. The actual page is allocated only when the data are written to.

Answer (score 2):

I just added MAP_PRIVATE to the second mmap and it worked. Reading malloc.c is what gave it away.